# URL Rewriting(.htaccess) index.php?page=foo&lang=en to /en/foo

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am new to the URL Rewriting using .htaccess and I am strugguling with it.

What I want is to change the url similar to this **http://www.example.org/index.php?page=contact&lang=en**  (lang has 3 options while the page value is changing depending on the current page) for example - 
to **https://example.org/en/contact** - non-www and https version).

Also if someone visits https://example.org/ I want to redirect them to https://example.org/en (default)

So far this is what I have in .htaccess and it doesn't work propertly.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^\w+$ index.php?page=$0&lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)(&lang=en)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

#1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#2
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en? [R=301,L]

#3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)&lang=(\w+)$
RewriteRule "(.*)" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%2/%1?" [R=301,L]
```

### Explanation

#### Block 1

Handles all Requests without https or with www.

http://www.example.org/whatever => https://example.org/whatever

#### Block 2

Handles root `/`  requests and add `en` as default language

https://example.org/ => https://example.org/en

#### Block 3

Handles the index.php?page=x&lang=x Requests and replace Query Params with Path segments

https://example.org/index.php?page=contact&lang=en => https://example.org/en/contact

All 3 together should fulfill your described requirements

http://www.example.org/index.php?page=contact&lang=en => https://example.org/en/contact

Comment: Thanks @Evil_skunk it only works partially. I had to disable the #2 block because I keep getting a 404 error. After disabling the #2 block if I land on the http://www.example.org/index.php?page=contact&lang=en it gets me redirected to the https://example.org/en/contact BUT I get 404 error. This "contact" from rewritten url gets to the server as ?page= param, right? And if I land on https://example.org/index.php?page=contact everything works fine and as soon as I add &lang param I get 404 error.

Comment: yes - `/index.php?page=contact&lang=en`  gets redirected to `/en/contact`. The query-Params (?page and &lang) are thrown away in that case. I thought your application is getting the relevant info from path not from query strings :-) . But if you remove the questionmark `?` in RewriteRule3, the query params will stay there => `/en/contact?page=contact&lang=en`

Comment: and for Rule 3 - I also expected your application to be able to handle `/en` requests. But feel free to adapt that and extend whatever your application needs

Comment: Thanks, @Evil_skunk for help. Now I get it. I will try to adapt my application to get info from the path.

Comment: @belmo  you're welcome. I thought that was the reason you want to redirect it. But you can always redirect it AND keep the URL params, so maybe you don't necessarily need to adapt your application

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `.htaccess` that matches your needs

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/index\.php)?
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/index\.php)?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\w+)&lang=(\w+)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2?
```

**Explanation**

The first condition and rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/index\.php)?
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en?
```

will redirect the following urls to `http://www.example.org/en`

```
http://www.example.org
http://www.example.org/
http://www.example.org/index.php
```

The second conditions and rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/index\.php)?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\w+)&lang=(\w+)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/%2?
```

will redirect the following urls to  http://www.example.org/contact/en`

```
http://www.example.org/index.php?page=contact&lang=en
http://www.example.org/?page=contact&lang=en
http://www.example.org?page=contact&lang=en
```

change `contact` and `en` with other values to see the changes

Here is a [Live example](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=37e6c1fe-4a21-503d-a485-9b1f12b8e263)

Comment: This gets me redirected to https://example.com/en which is good but the bad side is that I receive 404 Error because I need to rewrite the page=contact&lang=en to the https://example.com/en/contact.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I didn't read your question properly at first time. Fixed ! Regards.

Comment: Added some explanations and use cases